# bash node command :no such file or directory

Tags: bash, homebrew

I have uninstalled (manually) all files related to node, npm, nvm on my MacOs as I would like to start managing everything through homebrew.

After uninstalling everything, and installing node with `brew install nod -g`, I ran `node version`in my terminal to have the following error thrown at me:

`-bash: /Users/{username}/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/node: No such file or directory`

I am sure it has to do with a symlink somewhere that I should remove/edit, but I really have no clue where to find this and how to modify it.

Assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding the following to `.bash-profile`:

```
# Node path
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```